# Why can't I see https webpage after using sudo certbot --apache

Tags: apache, ssl, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and followed the Digital Ocean instructions to get my apache server up and running:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04

Which worked fine for HTTP traffic, then I used the Digital Ocean instructions (which I knew, but followed them anyway) to set up for SSL (https) access:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04

I selected the option to redirect all traffic to https. I opened my firewall using `sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'`.
But I am unable to see my sites - the browsers just timeout. I have tried disabling ufw just to see, and nope, nothing.

[image: SSL Labs gives: Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server]

SSL Labs just gives me an "Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server" error.

I also ran https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?q=juglugs.com

and it timed out:
[image: Check-your-website output]

I have deleted the letsencrypt stuff and ran through it again three times with the same result, and now I'm stuck...

Everything I've searched points to a firewall error, but as I've said, I've disabled that and have the same result. The router settings have not been changed since I did my fresh Ubuntu install.

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Port 443 isn't open on your IP address, check with virgin-media, or on your home router, if its open / forwarded to you web server

Comment: b.t.w. apache now supports managed domains (mod_md) which eliminate the need for certbot, or alternatives, which imho never work that well. (but I havn't tired them for a while)
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_md.html

Answer (score 0):

[on8tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081821/on8tom) answered this one for me - In setting up the new build of Ubuntu, my local IP address for the apache server had changed, and my Virgin Media Hub only had port 443 open to the old IP address.

Many thanks for pointing me at that (but I should have checked that before posting this - kicking myself!)